# Unity 2D: How to destroy just one prefab clone when clicked on

Tags: unity-game-engine, destroy

so I have a problem :D. I created a simple script that will instantiate a prefab of a ball on mouse coords when clicked onto the screen. Then I went on and created a second script. In the second script, wich was attached on the prefab of a ball, I tested for mouse click, when that happened I deleted a GameObject ball. I assigned the ball prefab to the GameObject variable ball. The only problem is (also the reason why this is not a dulplicate question, atleast I hope..) that when I click on the ball it deletes all the balls. I know that its happening because they are all basically just one prefab. I thought Ill solve it by giving seperate name to each prefab cline and then deleting them by name, but Im pretty shore unity has a better solution. I dont mind javascript or c# solutions, thanks!

PS: Im using the Destroy method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are listening to a mouse click in your second script but not checking if you're clicking on the ball. Instead you should be checking if the mouse is hitting your ball by casting a ray.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))
    {
        if(hit.collider.gameObject==gameObject) Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

edit-> for unity2d:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
{
   RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

   if(hit.collider != null)
  {
        if(hit.collider.gameObject==gameObject) Destroy(gameObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks that actually worked my miisunderstanding, sorry!

Comment: Ok, I tried to use this. It worked the first time but the it failed ater unity restart. Not working anymore its getting the mouse click (tested by print method) but not the if(Phy... Im using unity 2D

Comment: do you have a collider on the ball?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem, but in my case I've got an array of `GameObject[]` and choose some item in that array then clone it and display it randomly...

I encounter this since I have an array of `GameObject` and thinking of how should I destroy it specifically, because if I use loop it will destroy sequentially...

Well there's a tutorial on how to destroy.... video from Jay AnAm

```
void Update(){
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){

            BoxCollider bc = hit.collider as BoxCollider;
            if(bc != null){
                Destroy (bc.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure to add component of box colliider to the gameobject.

Check this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tknfsylens